# Is a join to a look-up table more optimal than a user defined scalar function?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a function and pass it an integer e.g. 99, 4 or 3

The function returns a different integer (so effectively it transforms it)

Now I have found that this function is called in a select so for a 300 row import with all my related tables the total times the number transform function is called is 250k times!

This scares me a lot - My question is would this be better in a look up table that is joined to my query - thus removing the function from the select.

Comment: did my suggestion worked for u?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would vote for look up table, as it can make use of the index of the table, if created
Also the function need not to be run for each row when running against a table

But one problem with look up table is that it should handle all possible inputs.
We can handle only limited cases with look up table.

So if you can create a look up table for all possible input, look up table has performance advantage over function

Answer (score 2):

Could you copy the logic from the function into your select statement?

e.g

```
SELECT (a.ValueA + a.ValueB) as [ValueC]
FROM SomeTable a
```

Answer (score 2):

For the 1st approach, I would suggest to write the query/logic(of the concerned function) in the select clause itself. You would definitely see a performance improvement. I too had a performance issue for 7,000,000  records. this helped me a bit. Although no. of times of execution will not reduce but it will definitely improve the performance as queries are quite faster then the functions